# Get the value of '[UNK]' in BERT

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I have designed a model based on BERT to solve NER task. I am using `transformers` library with the `"dccuchile/bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased"` pre-trained model. The problem comes when my model detect an entity but the token is `'[UNK]'`. How could I know which is the string behind that token?

I know that an unknown token can't be reverted to the original one, but I would like to at least capture that values before passing the inputs to the model.

The code is really simple:

```
    sentenceIds = tokenizer.encode(sentence,add_special_tokens = True)

    inputs = pad_sequences([sentenceIds], maxlen=256, dtype="long", 
                              value=0, truncating="post", padding="post")

    att_mask = torch.tensor([[int(token_id > 0) for token_id in inputs[0]]]).to(device)
    inputs = torch.tensor(inputs).to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():        
        outputs = model(inputs, 
                          token_type_ids=None, 
                          attention_mask=att_mask)
```

As you see is really simple, just tokenize, padding or truncating, creating attentionMask and calling to the model.

I have tried using `regex`, trying to find the two tokens that are around it and things like that, but I can't solve it properly.

Comment: It should be possible to find out what the word is. Can you share the code when tokenize and encode your input?

Comment: I have edited the question, adding the code-

Answer (score 3):

The tokenizer works in two steps. First, it does pre-tokenization, which is basically splitting on spaces and separating punctuation. Let's have a look at it on a random Czech sentence:

```py
tokenizer.basic_tokenizer.tokenize("Kočka leze dírou.")
```

This gives you: `['kocka', 'leze', 'dirou', '.']`

In the second step, it applies the word piece splitting algorithm, so you get:

```py
tokenizer.tokenize("Kočka leze dírou.")
```

You get: `['[UNK]', 'le', '##ze', 'di', '##ro', '##u', '.']`

If there is no way how to split the token into subwords, the whole word becomes `[UNK]`. Tokens starting with `##` get appended to the previous ones, so this way you can find out where the `[UNK]` originally came from.

(And it seems weird to me that Spanish WordPiece tokenizer cannot parse a word that only consists of Latin characters.)